# How can you create multiple S4 classes with similarly named methods in R?

Tags: r, class, software-design, r-s4

I am trying to build an R package with two S4 classes `Myclass` and `Mynewclass` which have similarly named methods `parameters` and `parameters<-`

```
#' Example docstring of Myclass
#'
#' @slot parameters_names names of the parameters which are used by the
#'     model.
#' @slot parameters parameters which are used by the
#'     model.
#'
#' @import tidyverse
#' @import reshape2
#' @importFrom methods new
#' @export Myclass
#' 
Myclass <- setClass('Myclass',
                    # slots
                    slots = c(
                      parameters_names = 'list',
                      parameters = 'list'
                    ),
                    
                    # prototypes for the slots, automatically set output and param
                    # names
                    prototype = list(
                      parameters_names = list('a', 'b'),
                      parameters = vector(mode = "list", length = 2)
                    )
)

# Setter and getter methods for parameters

#' Retrieves parameters Myclass.
#'
#' @param object An object of the class Myclass.
#'
#' @return parameter values of Myclass.
#' @rdname Myclass-class
#' @export
setGeneric('parameters',
           function(object) standardGeneric('parameters'))

#' @describeIn Myclass Retrieves parameters Myclass.
#'
#' @param object An object of the class Myclass.
#'
#' @return parameter values of Myclass.
#' @aliases parameters,ANY,ANY-method
#' @rdname Myclass-class
#' @export
setMethod('parameters', 'Myclass',
          function(object) object@parameters)

#' Sets parameters of Myclass,
#' 
#' @param object An object of the class Myclass
#' @param value a named list of (a, b).
#'
#' @return Updated version of Myclass.
#' @rdname Myclass-class
#' @export
setGeneric(
  'parameters<-',
  function(object, value){
    standardGeneric('parameters<-')
  })

#' @describeIn Myclass Sets parameters of Myclass.
#'
#' @param object An object of the class Myclass.
#' @param value a named list of (a, b).
#'
#' @return Updated version of Myclass.
#' @aliases parameters<-,ANY,ANY-method
#' @rdname Myclass-class
#' @export
setMethod(
  'parameters<-', 'Myclass',
  function(object, value) {
    a = value$a
    b = value$b
    ic <- list(a, b)
    # if all above tests are passed, assign the ic namelist to the object
    object@parameters <- ic
    
    return(object)
  })
```

and

```
#' Example docstring of Mynewclass
#'
#' @slot parameters_names names of the parameters which are used by the
#'     model.
#' @slot parameters parameters which are used by the
#'     model.
#'
#' @import tidyverse
#' @import reshape2
#' @importFrom methods new
#' @export Mynewclass
#' 
Mynewclass <- setClass('Mynewclass',
                    # slots
                    slots = c(
                      parameters_names = 'list',
                      parameters = 'list'
                    ),
                    
                    # prototypes for the slots, automatically set output and param
                    # names
                    prototype = list(
                      parameters_names = list('a', 'b', 'c'),
                      parameters = vector(mode = "list", length = 3)
                    )
)

# Setter and getter methods for parameters

#' Retrieves parameters Mynewclass.
#'
#' @param object An object of the class Mynewclass.
#'
#' @return parameter values of Mynewclass.
#' @rdname Mynewclass-class
#' @export
setGeneric('parameters',
           function(object) standardGeneric('parameters'))

#' @describeIn Mynewclass Retrieves parameters Mynewclass.
#'
#' @param object An object of the class Mynewclass.
#'
#' @return parameter values of Mynewclass.
#' @aliases parameters,ANY,ANY-method
#' @rdname Mynewclass-class
#' @export
setMethod('parameters', 'Mynewclass',
          function(object) object@parameters)

#' Sets parameters of Mynewclass,
#' 
#' @param object An object of the class Mynewclass
#' @param value a named list of (a, b, c).
#'
#' @return Updated version of Mynewclass.
#' @rdname Mynewclass-class
#' @export
setGeneric(
  'parameters<-',
  function(object, value){
    standardGeneric('parameters<-')
  })

#' @describeIn Mynewclass Sets parameters of Mynewclass.
#'
#' @param object An object of the class Mynewclass.
#' @param value a named list of (a, b, c).
#'
#' @return Updated version of Mynewclass.
#' @aliases parameters<-,ANY,ANY-method
#' @rdname Mynewclass-class
#' @export
setMethod(
  'parameters<-', 'Mynewclass',
  function(object, value) {
    a = value$a
    b = value$b
    c = value$c
    ic <- list(a, b, c)
    # if all above tests are passed, assign the ic namelist to the object
    object@parameters <- ic
    
    return(object)
  })
```

However, whenever I try to use `devtools::document()` the following error message appears

[Error in methods::getMethod(name, eval(call$signature), where = env) :
no method found for function 'parameters' and signature Myclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBUzw.png)

How can I solve this issue without having to give different names for the methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not calling `setGeneric` in both files.

It could be the case that the duplicate call to `setGeneric` creates a new generic, and gets rid of the previous one (including its associated method). This leaves you with a method only for `Mynewclass`.

See also
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2010-January/056396.html

Comment: Thank you! It seems to have solved the problem.